# How to get total cost and $valueFreeShipping inside file vendor/..../romcity/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules.js

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I don't want to load shipping method on City changed, if $valuePackage < $valueFreeShipping (because the shippinig cost in this case is zero)

How can I get these two values : **$valuePackage**(the total cart cost) and **$valueFreeShipping** (if total cart cost is greater than $valueFreeShipping , the shipping cost is zero) inside the file

**vendor/..../romcity/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules.js ?**

i need something like this

```
 if ($valuePackage < $valueFreeShipping) {
observableFields.push('city_id'); // Load shipping method on City_id changed
}
```

$valuePackage and $valueFreeShipping are not defined inside the file 
vendor/..../romcity/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules.js

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in block:

> ```
> public function getFreeShippingValue()
> {
>     return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
> }
> ```

in template:

```
$freeShipping = $block->getFreeShippingValue();

       <script>
           freeShipping = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $freeShipping ?>;
       </script>
```

totals cart:
in block:

> ```
> private $cartHelper;
> /**
>  * Pricing helper.
>  *
>  * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data
>  */
> private $pricingHelper;
>     \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper,
>     \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
> public function getCartHelper()
> {
>     return $this->cartHelper;
> }
> /**
>  * Get pricing helper.
>  *
>  * @return \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data
>  */
> public function getPricingHelper()
> {
>     return $this->pricingHelper;
> }
> ```

in template

```
$quote = $block->getCartHelper()->getQuote();          
$total = $quote->getSubtotal();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but how do I get these values inside the js file: vendor/..../romcity/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules.js ?

Comment: check my answer. add script tag in your template.